# how to convert an object to IEnumerable of that object

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I have a function returning me an object of type Person.

Now, I need to call another function that accepts `IEnumerable<Person>` type. How to do it please?

This function below returns me Person.

```
var objA = Service.GetAll(obj);
```

I need to call another method that is as follows

```
var result = Service.Get(AR<IEnumerable<Person>> name, type)
```

I specified name as `IEnumerable<Person>` because it takes that type.

**EDIT**

My second method takes this as parameter type.

```
AR<IEnumerable<Person>>
```

In all other places my first method returns `AR<Ienumerable<person>>` but in one case it returns `AR<Person>`. Now I need need to make it as a list i.e `AR<IEnumerable<Person>>` so that I can use second method as is

Comment: Do you mean you want to pass that person to a method that accept `IEnumerable<Person>` as parameter?  `var p = f1();` then call `f2(new Person[] { p });` Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @RezaAghaei: Nope, I am looking for something like IEnumerable<Person> should be passed as a parameter to second function while I get Person as return value in first function

Comment: So my answer is correct :)

Comment: @RezaAghaei: The best overloaded method for my second method has invalid arguments... Also remember, I have 2 parameters for 2nd function. One is the IEnumerable<Person> and another is type.

Comment: @Deevinee can you show the code that you have so that we can see what it is you are talking about for the 2nd function

Comment: @Deevinee and what's the type of `type` parameter?

Comment: @RezaAghaei: Thats a view. Its a controller code. All places it works fine but only in this condition, it doesnt because the freaking first method returns Person object and not IEnumerable of Person. My requirement is that simple

Comment: @RezaAghaei: In all other cases, freaking first method returns IEnumerable of Person. But sadly in my new requirement, it doesnt :p lol

Comment: I'm suspicious of this question. `var objA = Service.GetAll(obj);` is seriously badly named. You say it returns a `Person`?So, it's `GetAll` what? Person? That smells. Are you sure that your types are what you say they are. From the tone of your comments, I suspect not. Let's see more code, the ***specific*** error you're seeing from the compiler, and the interface/method declarations of all the code you're calling from the code you supplied above.

Comment: Please don't have magic types. What is `AR`? You need to post a [mcve].

Comment: Nobody knows how to construct an `AgentResult<T>`. What's clear is that you're wasting people's time by omitting details and changing "simple requirements" under the feet of those kind enough to help you. Get your question straight and ask it when it's properly formed.

Comment: Please replace the `var` keyword with the actual types too.

Comment: @spender: AR is just an object man. What else do you want? I am curious why are you after that, because all methods in the first function returns that but new method i made don't return Ienumerable. Its simple. I wanna make/cast it as ienumerable

Comment: @Deevinee - We can't pull data from an `AR<>` and we can't construct new `AR<>` types ***unless*** you **post the code** (and provide a [mcve]).

Comment: @spender: For obvious reason I am not using the naming convention from my project, but it is all same buddy. Sorry for that

Comment: @Deevinee You have ***completely*** changed the types in your methods three times since the inception of this misguided question. It's hard not to view this as timewasting.

Comment: @spender - Here here. I couldn't agree more.

Comment: @spender: Nope, type is same :( Please help me, I am really struggling . Its simple I need to put an object into list and send as parameter

Comment: @Deevinee - We can't help you to do anything with `AR<>` ***until you post the code for it***. Why is that difficult for you to do?

Comment: @Enigmativity: Its updated. My apologize that I didnt mention correctly. Now when I use any of the solutions here, I get error. What is the issue?

Comment: @Deevinee - What do you mean that it is updated? There hasn't been a change to the question. Can you please post a [mcve] (which would include the code for `AR<>` so that we can answer? ***We cannot tell you what is the issue is without the complete code.***

Comment: @Enigmativity: I have myself got a clean and simple solution. Thanks for your concern, appreciate it.

Comment: @Deevinee - Please post your solution as an answer.

Comment: @Deevinee - Ah, this question has been put on hold so you can't. Can you put the code on https://dotnetfiddle.net/ and share a link back here?

Answer (score 4):

In these rare cases I use an extension method like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> YieldMe<T>(this T obj)
{
    yield return obj;
}
```

Comment: damn, it says type of namespace T couldn't be found are you missing assembly ref :S

Comment: Show what you have done.

Comment: @Deevinee `T` is a generic, so you could replace it with your object `Person`

Comment: @Deevinee can you check your using section in the header and make sure you have 
`using System.Collections; and using System.Collections.Generic;` also show how you are calling the extension method

Comment: I've fixed the code.

Comment: also @Deevinee next time you ask a question please include the code.. it would have avoided lots of guess work in regards to commented questions

Comment: @HamletHakobyan sorry about that I meant to put the OP's name in the comment

Comment: @MethodMan Don't worry :)

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: Now your modified code doesn't throw compile error, all good, but how to use it?

Comment: Using a generator (`yield return`) for a single item is hugely costly compared to returning a single item array.

Comment: @spender: Please help me, it looks like a simple thing, why none of the answers helps my code :(

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: AgentResult<IEnumerable<Person>> is the parameter of second method.

Comment: @Deevinee what is `AgentResult`?

Comment: @Steve: That's internal object. But I don't think you should care about it. Do you?

Comment: This is an overly expensive to do it this way. The `yield` approach produced 118 lines of IL compared to replacing the yield with a basic array producing only 30 lines of IL.

Comment: @Deevinee, seems like we should since every answer posted here would have worked without that, and you would have got an answer much quicker had you posted that in the first place.

Comment: @Steve: Correctly put my code above, please help. Its simple. I need AR<IEnumerable<Person> from AR<Person>

Comment: @Deevinee your original question was how to convert an object to an IEnumerable. That's been answered. Stack Overflow is not here to do your work for you. I'm sure you can use the answers here and take the next step yourself, it it's simple as you say.

Comment: @Steve: Thank you, I am experimenting, thank you so much for your help. But I need an answer :( I am also trying buddy

Answer (score 2):

> I am looking for something like **`IEnumerable<Person>` should be passed
>   as a parameter to second function** while I get **Person as return value
>   in first function**

So you can use such code:

```
/*while I get Person as return value in first function*/
Person p = FirstMethod(); 

/*IEnumerable<Person> should be passed as a parameter to second function*/
SecondMethod(new Person[] { p });
```

While the the second method signature could be `void SecondMethod(IEnumerable<Person> x)`

Comment: sorry, your first line itself throws error

Comment: How could this answer be downvoted? While it does what you exactly described?

Comment: Reza, sorry, I didn't downvote. In fact, you attempted to help me. Really I didn't downvote but unfortunately this piece of code doesn't help

Comment: @RezaAghaei - It's being downvoted because the OP is making substantive changes to his question. New readers think our answers are just plain wrong because of the edits.

Comment: @Enigmativity Thank you for your comment :) I quoted what the the OP stated exactly and also I put part of his statement in the answer!

Comment: @RezaAghaei - Yes, you did and you did a good job, and then the OP changed his question to make your answer incorrect. My answer has similarly been downvoted.

Comment: @Enigmativity Anyway, thank you for your kind comment and +1 to your answer to destory the effect of that unreasonable downvote :)

Comment: @RezaAghaei - I've done the same. I think this question is about to be closed anyway.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is to start with:

```
public Person GetPerson()
{
    return new Person()
}
```

and add:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> GetPeople()
{
    return new [] { GetPerson() };
}
```

Comment: The blunt tool of a single-item array is probably the best answer here. Creating a state machine by using `yield` to answer this problem seems somewhat longwinded in comparison.

Comment: Didn't help me. My requirement is simple, it should take AgentResult<IEnumerable<Person>> as input of second function while I receive Person as output of first function.

Comment: @Deevinee - I answered your question as you had it. You've now edited your question. Please be mindful of that. I'll see if I can update, but you need to post a [mcve] if you expect good answers.

Comment: @Enigmativity: Ok, please help its simple I need AR<Ienumerable<Person>> from AR<Person>

Comment: @Deevinee - We have no idea what `AR<>` is. How can we possibly know how to extract the inner type? You need to post a [mcve]. Have you read that page yet?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new instance of `List<Person>` since `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx

So:

```
var person = FunctionThatGetsPerson();
List<Person> personList = new List<Person> { person };
FunctionThatTakesEnumerable(personList);

public void FunctionThatTakesEnumerable(IEnumerable<Person> personList)
{ 
    //
}
```

Comment: yours seems easy but it says it has invalid argument in the personlist line

Comment: Is the person object a type of `Person`?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just create an inline array?
`FunctionThatTakesEnumerable(new Person[] {person} );`

Comment: @Puddler I mean that's essentially what I'm doing in an extra line but using Generics.

Comment: New list is a new object. New object is a new resource. Also, List can be modified even if you put IEnumerable to the method by simple type cast.

Comment: @Puddler: It doesn't work mate

Comment: @VadimMartynov: It says it has some invalid arguments for the best overloaded method. Doesn't work :(

Comment: @Deevinee you might have to edit your question to include the code you already have.

Comment: @Deevinee: I think you need to post your code up in your initial question.

I think there is a little more to the question then we can currently see

Comment: @Puddler:AgentResult<IEnumerable<Person>>

Answer (score 1):

Just [use](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2012/05/03/c.net-little-wonders-the-enumerable.repeat-static-method.aspx)

```
Enumerable.Repeat(objA, 1);
```

[Repeat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb348899(v=vs.100).aspx) returns exactly what you need.

Comment: @Deevinee [Repeat returns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb348899(v=vs.100).aspx) exactly what you need

Comment: Mate, how to use it?

Comment: It is throwing compile time error mate